# Docpad: confused about extending template data

Tags: docpad

I'm totally confused about adding mongo data to template data. I haven't even started trying to get the data from a database as I can't get my templates to see test data (see below). This is in docpad.coffee for the moment, but ultimately g will be the output of mongoDB.

```
events:

    extendTemplateData: (opts) ->
        # {templateData} = opts

        getGigsData: ->
            g = { "date" : "3-4-2013", "location" : "Gent" }
            return g

        opts.templateData["getGigsData"] = getGigsData
```

And I hope to access it with `<%= @getGigsData().date %>`
Thanks so much for some guidance

I should add that this design is based on wanting to make it easy for the band to add gigs, without letting them edit the page content itself as I fear they would mess up the markup - if there are other ways to achieve this goal, I'd be pleased to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this locally. And hit the issue:

```
debug: Emitting the event: extendTemplateData
    → [2014-02-14 01:38:50.030] [/Users/balupton/Projects/docpad-extras/skeletons/so-21747504/node_modules/docpad/out/lib/docpad.js:1184] [DocPad.emitSerial]
error: Something went wrong with the action
    → [2014-02-14 01:38:50.037] [/Users/balupton/Projects/docpad-extras/skeletons/so-21747504/node_modules/docpad/out/lib/interfaces/console.js:107] [ConsoleInterface.destroyWithError]
error: An error occured: 
ReferenceError: getGigsData is not defined
    at Object.docpadConfig.events.extendTemplateData (/Users/balupton/Projects/docpad-extras/skeletons/so-21747504/docpad.coffee:42:44)
    at ambi (/Users/balupton/Projects/docpad-extras/skeletons/so-21747504/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/ambi/out/lib/ambi.js:25:27)
    at DocPad.<anonymous> (/Users/balupton/Projects/docpad-extras/skeletons/so-21747504/node_modules/docpad/out/lib/docpad.js:995:25)
    at ambi (/Users/balupton/Projects/docpad-extras/skeletons/so-21747504/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/ambi/out/lib/ambi.js:23:18)
    at Task.<anonymous> (/Users/balupton/Projects/docpad-extras/skeletons/so-21747504/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/event-emitter-grouped/out/lib/event-emitter-grouped.js:45:23)
    at ambi (/Users/balupton/Projects/docpad-extras/skeletons/so-21747504/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/ambi/out/lib/ambi.js:23:18)
    at fire (/Users/balupton/Projects/docpad-extras/skeletons/so-21747504/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:163:25)
    at b (domain.js:183:18)
    at Domain.run (domain.js:123:23)
    at Task.fire (/Users/balupton/Projects/docpad-extras/skeletons/so-21747504/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:173:25)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)
```

Which indicates that the error is actually inside our event handler, rather than inside our code. That for some reason `getGigsData` is not being set, despite our:

```
    getGigsData: ->
        g = { "date" : "3-4-2013", "location" : "Gent" }
        return g
```

Examining the code, as a CoffeeScript user, I found the issue. As a non-coffeescript user, you can use the coffeescript compiler on the coffeescript website http://coffeescript.org to see the compiled javascript, which is:

```
({
  events: {
    extendTemplateData: function(opts) {
      ({
        getGigsData: function() {
          var g;
          g = {
            "date": "3-4-2013",
            "location": "Gent"
          };
          return g;
        }
      });
      return opts.templateData["getGigsData"] = getGigsData;
    }
  }
});
```

As we can see that is definitely not what we expected. We are just defining getGigsData inside an object, then doing nothing with it.

The issue is that we used a colon instead of an equals sign, so `getGigsData: ->` instead of `getGigsData = ->`. This is not a coffeescript thing, but you would have run into the same issue if this was javascript too, albeit javascript may be a bit more obvious due to the necessary squiggly braces around object definitions.

As a sidenote, if you prefer to use JavaScript with DocPad for whatever reason, that is totally supported. You could use a `docpad.json` or `docpad.js` file for your docpad configuration file. Another option, is to continue using CoffeeScript then just wrap JavaScript code within the backtick, see: http://coffeescript.org/#embedded

Comment: That fixed stage 1, but I am still stuck on the mongoose part [https://github.com/simonh1000/docpad-plugin-mongo/blob/master/src/mongo.plugin.coffee](code).  It is finding it as the console.dir command looks good, but I am not sure how to connect to docpad - at present you see a nested set of `return` commands, but that isn't working.  My first attempt to pass the `opts` to getGigsData did not seem to improve things. I've tried to follow the example code but to no avail

Comment: Can you ask that as a separate question, and I'll happily follow up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772015/docpad-adding-to-templatedate-via-callback